# How will i able to add this two numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two number that calculates the amount and vat amount using JavaScript. Now how will I be able to do this?

```html
<tr>
  <th>Amount: </th>
  <td><input id="amount" type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" required />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>VAT 20% Amt: </th>
  <td>
    <input id="vatAmt" type="text" name="vatAmount" class="form-control" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Total Amount: </th>
  <td>
    <span id="totalAmount"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

then the amount due

```
<div class="col-md-6" >
    <h3>Amount Due: £ <span id="amountValue"></span></h3>   
</div>
```

My JavaScript code is below:

```js
$("#amount").keyup(function () {

  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#amountValue").text(value);

});

$("#vatAmt").keyup(function () {

    var valueVat = $(this).val();
    var sum = value + valueVat;
    $("#totalAmount").text(sum);

}).keyup();
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: can you post your code? hmmm

Comment: Apologies that is just a running joke about doing everything with jQuery..
Can you explain more what issue you are facing and what you can figure out? And what error you may be getting?

Comment: the two values will compute then display on the amount due

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` isn't defined in your second `keyup` handler.  You need to define it:

```
$("#vatAmt").keyup(function () {

    var value = $("#amount").val(); // <--- here
    var valueVat = $(this).val();
    var sum = value + valueVat;
    $("#totalAmount").text(sum);

}).keyup();
```

When you define a variable inside a function, it's only available within that function.  Another option could be to define it globally, but I generally prefer keeping scope limited to only where you need it.  Within your `keyup` handler for `#varAmt` you need two values, so you would have two calls to `.val()` to get two values.

Note: It's *possible* you may also want to use `parseInt` or something similar to perform your addition:

```
$("#vatAmt").keyup(function () {

    var value = parseInt($("#amount").val()); // <--- here
    var valueVat = parseInt($(this).val()); // <--- and here
    var sum = value + valueVat;
    $("#totalAmount").text(sum);

}).keyup();
```

JavaScript is pretty forgiving about types, but sometimes bugs can creep in if you rely on that.  And `.val()` returns a string because the input is text, even if that text happens to be numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
<tr>
  <th>Amount: </th>

  <td><input id="amount" type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" required />

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>VAT 20% Amt: </th>
  <td>
    <input id="vatAmt" type="number" name="vatAmount" class="form-control" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Total Amount: </th>
  <td>
    <span id="totalAmount"></span>
  </td>
</tr>



<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3>Amount Due: £ <span id="amountValue"></span></h3>

</div>




var value;
$("#amount").keyup(function() {
   value = $(this).val();
 $("#amountValue").text(value);

})

$("#vatAmt").keyup(function() {
    var valueVat = $(this).val();
    var sum = Number(value) + Number(valueVat);

    $("#totalAmount").text(sum);
  }).keyup();
```